# C++ from 11 to 17

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

При переходе данный код заголовка перестал работать

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<limits>
  const double _infinity=
     std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
  const double pi= 4.*std::atan(1.);
  const double e = std::exp(1.);
  inline double display(double x){
     std::cout.precision(16);
     std::cout<<x;return 0;}
  inline double display(int x){
     std::cout<<x;return 0;}
  inline double display(char x){
     std::cout<<x;return 0;}
  inline double display(const char* x){
     std::cout<<x;return 0;}
  inline double display(bool x){
     std::cout<<'#'<<(x ? 't' : 'f');return 0;}
  inline double newline(){
    std::cout<< std::endl;return 0;}
  inline double remainder(double x, double y)
    { return std::fmod(x, y);}
  inline double quotient(double x, double y)
    { return std::floor(x / y);}
  inline double expt(double x, double y)
    { return std::pow(x, y);}
  inline double abs(double x) { return std::fabs(x);}
using std::sin;using std::cos;
using std::tan;using std::exp;
using std::log;using std::atan;
using std::sqrt;
```

Ошибки:

> Ошибка    C2382   abs: переопределение; разные спецификации исключений
>
> Предупреждение    C28251  Несогласованная аннотация для "remainder":
>   данный экземпляр содержит нет аннотаций. См. c:\program files
>   (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(530).
>   Примечание. Для данной функции имеется несколько прототипов. Это
>   предупреждение сравнивает первый прототип с номером экземпляра 3.
>     lb1 c:\users\bbcca\onedrive\рабочий стол\microlisp\lb1\mlisp.h  22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Название вашей функции `remainder` совпадает с [`std::remainder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder) из `<cmath>`.

Обычно это не проблема, ведь пространства имен разные, но судя по https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers

> ... `cxxx` headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the global namespace ...

хедерам вида `c___` (оставшимся от С) разрешается все свое содержимое, в дополнение к `namespace std`, объявлять также в глобальном пространстве имен.

Это здесь и происходит, `std::remainder` объявляется еще и как просто `remainder`.

Ничего не поделаешь, переименовывайте свою функцию. Или убирайте в `namespace`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема вроде как очевидна - объявление в глобальном пространстве символов с именем, уже используемым в бибилиотечном коде. Добавляйте новый символы в собственное пространство имен с уникальным именем, ну или используйте уникальные имена при добавлении в глобальное пространство имен.